# Compiler caused by unnecessary(?) instantiation of class template with incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I've got a template class that fails instantiation, if the template argument is an incomplete class.

```
template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    char m_buffer[sizeof(T)]; // breaks on instantiation, if T is an incomplete type
};
```

One translation unit using references to a instantiation of this class with an incomplete class as template argument works only, if a forward declaration of this class is visible, but not if the class template definition is available. Why does this happen?

---

##### Full Code

**a.hpp**

```
#define DEFINE_FOO_IN_HPP 1 // change this define to 0 to make the code work

template<class T>
struct Foo
#if DEFINE_FOO_IN_HPP
{
    char m_buffer[sizeof(T)]; // breaks on instantiation, if T is an incomplete type
}
#endif
;

struct Bar;

Foo<Bar>& FooBarInstance();
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.hpp"

struct Bar
{
    int m_v;
};

#if !DEFINE_FOO_IN_HPP
template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    char m_buffer[sizeof(T)]; // breaks on instantiation, if T is an incomplete type
};
#endif

Foo<Bar>& FooBarInstance()
{
    static Foo<Bar> val;
    return val;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "a.hpp"

void f(Foo<Bar>&)
{
    std::cout << "it works\n";
}

int main()
{
    f(FooBarInstance());
}
```

**Error (MSVC)**

```
1>main.cpp
1>...\a.hpp(7,1): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Bar'
1>...\a.hpp(12,8): message : see declaration of 'Bar'
1>...\main.cpp(12,21): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Foo<Bar>' being compiled
```

**Error(GCC)**

```
In file included from /app/main.cpp:3:
a.hpp: In instantiation of 'struct Foo<Bar>':
/app/main.cpp:12:21:   required from here
/app/a.hpp:7:19: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Bar'
    7 |     char m_buffer[sizeof(T)]; // breaks on instantiation, if T is an incomplete type
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
```

Neither GCC nor MSVC complain if the define in `a.hpp` is changed to

```
#define DEFINE_FOO_IN_HPP 0
```

leaving only a forward declaration of the class template visible during the compilation of `main.cpp`

Comment: Weirdly placed semi in the header. Don't think it'll cause trouble, though.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree that the macro doesn't really add to readability here, but the purpose was to either have a forward declaration of a definition of `template<class T> struct Foo` and this was code with the least amount of duplication that didn't sacrifice too much readability... (You are referring to the semicolon after `#endif`, right?)

Comment: The `Foo<Bar>` class will be instantiated when the compiler parses the `FooBarInstance` function declaration in the header file. And by that time there's no full definition of `Bar` yet, in either translation unit. There's no definition at all in the `main.cpp` source file. All this is leading to the errors you get.

Comment: My brain was drawing in a semi at the end of `Foo`'s definition which clearly isn't there after I managed to slap the brain down. Probably doing its best to see the same `Foo` in the header and the source file.

Comment: Try to declare something that uses a `sizeof()` of an incomplete class, and see what happens. This has nothing to do with templates.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @SamVarshavick The compiler error is provoked intentionally and I know what the compiler is complaining about. The thing that surprises me is that the compiler is perfectly fine with knowing `Foo<Bar>` is a `struct`, but adding more info (= class definition) breaks things...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler instantiates `Foo<Bar>` to check if there are any friend function declarations of `f` that it can find via ADL that can be called with a `Foo<Bar>` object.

Just qualify the call to suppress ADL:

```cpp
int main()
{
    ::f(FooBarInstance());
    (f)(FooBarInstance());
}
```

---

[[basic.lookup.argdep]p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.argdep#1)

> When the *postfix-expression* in a function call is an *unqualified-id*, other namespaces not considered during the usual unqualified lookup may be searched, and in those namespaces, namespace-scope friend function or function template declarations ([class.friend]) not otherwise visible may be found. These modifications to the search depend on the types of the arguments (and for template template arguments, the namespace of the template argument).

[[basic.lookup.argdep]p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.argdep#2):

> For each argument type `T` in the function call, there is a set of zero or more *associated namespaces* and a set of zero or more *associated entities* (other than namespaces) to be considered. The sets of namespaces and entities are determined entirely by the types of the function arguments (and the namespace of any template template argument). [...] The sets of namespaces and entities are determined in the following way:
>
> - [...]
> - If `T` is a class type (including unions), its associated entities are: the class itself; [...]
> - [...]

So `Foo<Bar>` is an associated entity and `::` (the global namespace) is an associated namespace.

[[basic.lookup.argdep]p(4.3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.argdep#4.3):

> Any namespace-scope friend functions or friend function templates ([class.friend]) declared in classes with reachable definitions in the set of associated entities are visible within their respective namespaces even if they are not visible during an ordinary lookup ([namespace.memdef]).

So a friend function declared inside `Foo<Bar>` in the scope of `::` should be visible. So when `Foo` has a reachable definition, it needs to be looked in for friend function definitions, which is why it is instantiated. This is also why it is fine when you have `DEFINE_FOO_IN_HPP=0`, since there is no longer a reachable definition.